# Start timer when the user starts filling a form in jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, timer

I'm quite new to jQuery and I'd like to do something that I believe should not be that complicated: I'd like to start a 60-second timer when the user starts filling in a form. When the timer reaches 0, it triggers other functions.

What I've got so far:

```
$('form').click(function(){
        $(function(){
          var count = 60;
          countdown = setInterval(function(){
            $("p#timer").html(count);
            if (count == 0) {
              $("p#sentence").html("Time's up! You lost.");
              $("form").addClass('lost');
              clearInterval(countdown);
            }
            count--;
          }, 1000);
        });
    });
```

This code works and does exactly what I want it to do. The *only* problem is that, when the user clicks on another part of the form (say, another input), it starts a second timer that isn't synchronized with the first one and sort of overwrites it. Basically, each time the user clicks on the form, another timer starts and things get ugly.

Now, having seen that, it seems pretty logic that this very bit of code would do that.
Yet, I just don't know what to do to prevent it from happening.

I tried to give a class to the form and remove it after the user has clicked:

```
$('form.timer_idle').click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('timer_idle');
        $(function(){
          var count = 60;
          countdown = setInterval(function(){
            $("p#timer").html(count);
            if (count == 0) {
              $("p#sentence").html("Time's up! You lost.");
              $("form").addClass('lost');
              clearInterval(countdown);
            }
            count--;
          }, 1000);
        });
    });
```

I hoped it would work, but it didn't. The class .timer_idle was indeed removed after the first click, but it didn't stop the script to run afterwards.

Comment: You should really consider to accept the Answer that helped you to resolve your issue or people will stop answer to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function to register a handler for the first event only.

Replace:

```
$('form').click(function(){
```

With:

```
$('form').one('click',function(){
```

This function is document just like all the others but it seems like only few are aware of its existence.

**Tip:**

When you *"help"* jQuery selector engine with extra details to the *id-selector* it prevents jQuery from using the native `document.getElemenyById` function:

```
$("p#sentence").html("Time's up! You lost.");
```

Better be:

```
$("#sentence").html("Time's up! You lost.");
```

[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

> For id selectors, jQuery uses the JavaScript function document.getElementById(), which is extremely efficient. When another selector is attached to the id selector, such as h2#pageTitle, jQuery performs an additional check before identifying the element as a match.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot for the tip! I indeed wasn't aware of the .one function and it'll probably make things much easier for me in the future. That was fast! ;-)

Comment: @TomS. No problem, welcome to stackoverflow, hope you'll enjoy the site.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling:

```
$('form.timer_idle').unbind('click');
```

This will remove the previously bound click event.

Comment: Thank you for that solution as well! It did work just fine too. I chose to go with gdoron's for its simplicity. Your answer has taught me something I didn't know, though. :-)

Comment: Agreed, the 'one' binding function makes more sense.

Comment: @TomS. If you read the docs I referenced about `one` you will see it actually uses `unbind`, but it gives it to you out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved simply by using a flag

```
var started = false;

$('form').click(function(){
    if(started){
        return;
    }

    started = true;

    // start timer to count down
});
```

​